# How to implement Slider Effect for pages?

Tags: nodes

I have few pages in my site and I want 4 specific pages to be rendered as **slider** with the full content of the node appeared as a slide.

On a desktop I want the slides to change using `html` arrows and on mobile I can `swipe` the slides.

I checked for contributed modules but mostly which I came across have been developed for photo galleries.

Is there a way to implement swipe for pages in mobile view and slider for specific pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the JavaScript library a module uses.

I use the Flex Slider https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider that it have both arrows for desktop and swipe for mobile.

I can't understand what you want to achieve (static?), but:

- I think the best way it to create a new content type (let's say slider) to upload images that will be used by the slider plus a taxonomy field that you will specify the slider you want to display the image.
- Then create a slider view with a filter based on that taxonomy.
- Finally render the view as a block.

-- EDIT --

So, you want to create a slider that will present nodes.

Let's say we have two content types Article & Basic, with fields: Title, Description, Image, Taxonomy.

1. Create a View
2. Format: FlexSlider, Show: Fields
3. Fields: Title, Description, Image etc
4. Filter criteria: Content type->Article, Basic
5. Save
6. Edit the appearance of the slider with css
7. Enjoy

The nodes will be pre-loaded and there will be no waitting time from slide to slide (but it will take longer to load the page).

Comment: Yes I do check flex slider but it does only for galleries. Eg: If I have created 4 nodes "node/1 , node/2, node/3, node/4" all four nodes have images and content which has been created already using a content type. I need to implement slider as like the url I shared above and I need to go back & forth using the arrows for all the nodes I have created ?
Sorry, If my question is not proper above.

Comment: @Nivas so you want to create a slider with nodes? And display, let's say: Title, Main image, Description, Custom field?

Comment: Absolutely right. Also those nodes will below to different content types and also I need to load it without reloading the page when clicking on the arrows or swiping in device.

Comment: @Nivas check the edit above :)